# Matlab: processing audio signal in very small frame sizes makes the audio disappear completely

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, noise, pitch-shifting

I am writing a pitch adaptation function in matlab. It takes an audio signal and a pitchCoefficient vector, where each element determines by how much to pitch shift its respective frame.

The audio signal is sliced evenly depending on how many pitch coefficients there are. If there are only 2 pitch coefficients the audio will be divided into 2 halves, and the first half will be pitch shifted by the first coefficient and the second half will be pitch shifted by the second coefficient. So if my coefficients are [1,2] the first half of the audio signal will sound the same as the original and the second half of the audio will be twice as high pitched.

This is the code for my function:

```
function [audioModified] = modifyPitch(audio, pitchCoefficients)

nwindows = length(pitchCoefficients);
windowSize = floor(length(audio)/nwindows);
audioModified = [];
for i=1:nwindows
    start = (i-1)*windowSize + 1;
    finish = i*windowSize;
    originalWindow = audio(start:finish, 1);
    pitchCoeff = 1/pitchCoefficients(i);
    timeScaledWindow = pvoc(originalWindow, pitchCoeff);
    [P,Q] = rat(pitchCoeff);
    pitchModifiedWindow = resample(timeScaledWindow, P, Q);
    audioModified = [audioModified; pitchModifiedWindow];
end

end
```

However, the final audio (which is the concatenation of all the frames) has these artifacts where each frame starts with a 'tic' sound. I'm assuming this happens because of the way I concatenate the frames. If the frames are too small this effect becomes so pronounced that the audio is no longer hearable.

How should I go about mitigating or removing this problem? Is there a way to smooth the audio out the same way you can blur an image to get rid of noise?

Additional info: I use [this phase vocoder](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/labrosa/matlab/pvoc/) (pvoc) to do the time scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overlapping and cross-fading longer frames instead of using frames that are too small.  The cross fade will help reduce the discontinuity between adjacent (re)synthesized frames.

Answer (score 1):

In audio processing, any sudden jumps in amplitude (ie steeper than the current sampling rate allows) will sound like clicks, and are considered an error. So if your algorithm just suddenly changes samples in a window, chances are if you look at the resultant waveform (say in Audacity or something similar) you'll see the level make a hard rise, which is in effect producing component frequencies over the nyquist (half the sampling rate), meaning the system can't accurately represent them and they'll cause audible artifacts. There's no easy solution for that, unfortunately you can't just do things to digital audio and hope it will work, there's boat loads of DSP involved in making sure your process is representable at the current sampling rate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think for your problem it might be sufficient to adjust the window dynamically in a way, that each window starts and ends at a point where your signal crosses zero. To get this done right you might need a higher resolution in your matlab raw data.